# use PrivateObject in .net 5 from nugget MSTest.TestFramework

Tags: c#, mstest, .net-5

PrivateObject is not available anymore in .net 5

I saw the code of this class is available in github microsoft/testfx
https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/664ac7c2ac9dbfbee9d2a0ef560cfd72449dfe34/src/TestFramework/Extension.Desktop/PrivateObject.cs

This code seems to be embeded in nugget MSTest.TestFramework 2.2.4

However in my .net5 project , I use this nugget but PrivateObject does not appear to be available

[image: packages]

[image]

[image]

Do you think it is possible to use PrivateObject from nugget MSTest.TestFramework 2.2.4 in a .net5 framework project?